# Facebook Like button doesn't align with other social buttons. Used CSS to fix that but breaks in other browsers

Tags: html, css, facebook

**CSS:**

```
.share {
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="share">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://bronies.info/" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" style="width:47px; overflow:hidden; top:-3px; left:3px;"></div>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Wondered what the bronies were all about?" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
    <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300" style="width:32px; overflow:hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

**Chrome, Safari:**

[image: Chrome and Safari]

**Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Opera:**

[image: Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Opera]

If you can see what I did in my HTML `style` property, I used `top:-3px`, and I did this before testing my website out on other browsers (Chrome is my primary web browser). I used `top` because a quick Google search led me a page instructing me to do so. Now that this solution doesn't work, how would I adjust it to align **and** work on all web browsers?

Comment: I recommend using `position:relative;` then specify it `top:0px; left:0px;` (of course you need to put the correct number when you align it.

Comment: @shnisaka Put `position:relative;` and `top:0px; left:0px;` in what? If you're talking about the CSS, I tried that but it still doesn't work, in fact it creates another issue (the gap between Like and Tweet is increased).

Comment: jeremy ahn look at @jimp answer and you will understand.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have been wondering "what the bronies were all about"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should remove `top:-3px;` completely. Because you don't have `position:relative;`, which is required (something other than `static`) to activate positioning, then Webkit (Chrome, Safari) is correctly ignoring it, but Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Opera are mistakenly honoring it (-3px shift).

**EDIT:**

*From the comments...*
Facebook's script adds a `<span>` inside your `<div>` which then triggers a CSS rule they also provide: `.fb_iframe_widget span { vertical-align: text-bottom; }`. I suggest adding `float: left;` to all three of your `<div>` tags so they will not share a common flow (or baseline).

Comment: I replaced `top:-3px;` with `position:relative;`. Now it looks good on the three browsers while the button is a few pixels down on Webkit. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: What happens if you also remove `position:relative;` to try static positioning?

Comment: http://imgur.com/zVEd2 - That's how it looks like on Webkit. On the other three browsers, it's aligned with the other buttons on the y factor but the gap between the Like and Tweet is bigger than the one between Tweet and +1. To clarify, the `style` of the Like button is `width:47px; overflow:hidden;` now that I removed the `top`, `position`, and `left`.

Comment: I'm guessing Facebook's JavaScript must be setting a height or top margin or padding or positioning. Do you have a live example or jsFiddle I could DOM inspect?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LzAZw/ - Since share buttons don't work offline, the buttons don't seem to show on the jsFiddle. Do whatever you need to do if you can.

Comment: I added the Facebook Like Button script from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and Google+ script from here: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag. I took out the Twitter tag because I see the shift without it. I'm looking at the DOM now.

Comment: Okay. I see what is happening. Facebook's script adds a <span> inside your <div> which then triggers a CSS rule they also provide: `.fb_iframe_widget span { vertical-align: text-bottom; }`. I suggest adding `float: left;` to all three of your `<div>` tags so they will not share a common flow (or baseline). That is working for me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you replied - I'm new here! And it seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

My solution is:

```
.fb-like.fb_iframe_widget span{
  vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try using `top: auto` and look at the result, check and see if it is in the same position in all browsers. If it needs to be aligned virtually then use `bottom: 3px;` (or any appropriate value that suites your need)

- do not forget you have to position:relative; to your code

so the final styling for the facebook button should look something like this :

```
width:47px; overflow:hidden;position:relative; top:auto;  bottom:3px; left:3px;
```

Comment: Copied and pasted the final styling but removed `bottom`. Without it, it seems to be lower than the other buttons. Added it, and it works fine on Webkit while breaking on other browsers.

Comment: instead of using `bottom:3px;` try using `padding-bottom:3px;` or `margin-bottom:3px;` it should work!

Comment: I just tried that. On Webkit, the button is lower. On the other three browsers, the button is at the right place while the other buttons are being pushed down.

Comment: Just did that and removed `padding-bottom`. Works on other three browsers while not working on Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: middle;` for container of Facebook button ...

Comment: I get the same exact results visually; correct on Webkit and above other buttons on the other browsers.

Comment: Well then like others asked, a live example will be needed to see what exactly is affecting it.

Answer (score 1):

I added `vertical-align: text-bottom;` to the `<span>` enclosing each button (to match what Facebook does), and everything lines up perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. (My spans also have `display: inline-block` if that matters.)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your "share" div. I don't know how it looks on other browsers but it seems to make things line up in Chrome.

```
font-size: 0.1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping each button in their own div, and setting the div to

`display:inline-block;  white-space: nowrap; vertical-align:top;`

and then added the following to the facebook specific div:

```
#facebookButton > div > span {vertical-align:baseline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following style to my css aligned the facebook share button with other social icons.

```
 .fb_iframe_widget{vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution: Wrap each social button by an `inline-block` element. And each social button has `display` attribute is `block`

**HTML**

```
<div class="social-share clearfix">
    <div class="social-share-item">
        <div id="fb-like" class="fb-like" data-href="{url}" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="social-share-item">
        <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet</a>
    </div>
    <div class="social-share-item">
        <div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.social-share {
    display: block;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.social-share-item > * {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.social-share-item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with mobile browsers and solved it with the following:

```
.fb-like span{
    vertical-align: initial !important;
}
```